# Are there any alternatives to getting a Verisign or similar cert for running Powershell scripts on any server?

Tags: powershell, code-signing

I've been working on a Powershell script for a little while, which is designed to be used both by me personally (on my local machine) and by other people both in my domain and outside of it.

The problem is, when someone other than me tries to run the script, they're greeted with the following error:

```
The file C:\my_script.ps1 cannot be loaded. The execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "Get-Help about_signing" for more details.
```

I thought I had taken care of this by changing the policy on the other employee's workstation to allow remotesigned within the script itself, but according to [this link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SigningPowerShellScripts.aspx), I'll need something a bit more robust.

Since the idea is to allow this to run, self-contained, on both internal and external machines, I'd rather not force the script to change things to unrestricted. Are there other options? Could I wrap this up in some other way (one person recommended a .NET container) project or something to allow it to run cleaner and be more self-contained?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your problem. You can use makecert on the machine where you wan't to execute the script:

```
@echo off
makecert -n "CN=PowerShell Local Certificate Root" -a sha1 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 -r -sv root.pvk root.cer -ss Root -sr LocalMachine
pause
makecert -pe -n "CN=PowerShell User" -ss MY -a sha1 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 -iv root.pvk -ic root.cer
```

then, sign your script:

```
$cert = @(Get-ChildItem cert:CurrentUser\My -codesigning)[0]
Set-AuthenticodeSignature <your script path> $cert | Out-Null
```

The "self containing" part shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Don't forget to set the execution policy to AllSigned or RemoteSigned, otherwise it still won't execute your script

Comment: Huh, interesting. So I could put the first bit in the .bat file that I'm using to fire off the script in the first place, and it would create the necessary cert and attach it successfully? I'll admit that I'm not terribly familiar with certs, so I wasn't sure if it would actually accept a cert that is created within the script.

The problem I'm having is that I need it to be able to be run by non-technical people, so I'd have to automate the makecert process, but if I can put that bit in the .bat file and the rest in the script itself, that should work great.